# How do I setup an authoritative name server with tinydns?

Tags: server, dns

I want to use [tinydns](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html) to serve up DNS records for my domain name. What is a minimal example of how to set this up in Ubuntu? You can assume that I've already set the name server for the domain to point to the IP of my server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `tinydns` (which is included with `djbdns`) and other required packages:

```
aptitude install djbdns daemontools-run make
```

Once the `daemontools-run` package is installed, we need to start it manually the first time (it will start automatically on boot):

```
initctl start svscan
```

`tinydns` needs two users to run. Create them now:

```
adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --group tinydns
adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --group dnslog
```

Create the service configuration directory in the [standard location](http://smarden.org/runit/faq.html#create):

```
mkdir -p /etc/sv
```

Run `tinydns-conf` to create the skeleton for the service:

```
tinydns-conf tinydns dnslog /etc/sv/tinydns <server-ip>
```

where `tinydns` and `dnslog` are the names of the user accounts that we previously created; `<server-ip>` is the IP address on the server that `tinydns` will listen on.

An empty [`tinydns-data`](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns-data.html) file (analogous to BIND's zone file) will have been created at `/etc/sv/tinydns/root/data`. You will need to edit it and enter in the details for your domain. See [the official documentation](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns-data.html) and [this](http://thedjbway.b0llix.net/djbdns/tinydns-data.html) for details on what to enter and example data files.

Whenever you make changes to the `tinydns-data` file, you must rebuild the `tinydns` database:

```
cd /etc/sv/tinydns/root
make
```

A file named `data.cdb` should have been created in the same directory.

Finally, enable the `tinydns` service by running:

```
update-service --add /etc/sv/tinydns
```

You should see `tinydns` running in `ps`. You can verify that your DNS server is serving up requests correctly by running something like this:

```
dig @<server-ip> <your-domain-name> ANY
```